# IBM x3500 Server managament/monitoring tool

Tags: network-monitoring, ibm, hardware, ibm-xseries, system-monitoring

I took over monitoring an older IBM x3500 7977 server and i don't have much knowledge of IBM servers.
I'm looking for the equivalent of Dell Server Administrator from IBM, just to monitor and alert on hardware failures, envronmental indicators (voltages, temperatures, fans, etc.)

There is nothing of that sort installed on the server, only a RAID array manager.

Does anybody know what kind of free tools does IBM offer for that?

I looked it up and all i could find was Tivoli and System Director, both are centralized dedicated server based management systems, i'm looking for something monitor a standalone server.

Comment: Do you have an existing monitoring infrastructure in place? IBM has monitoring packs for Systems Center Operations Manager and some other tools, but I'm not aware of anything standalone that will alert you to failures other than degraded RAID arrays (and that ServeRAID manager is a memory-hogging behemoth besides).

Comment: I'm using Level Platforms to monitor the infrastrcuture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuring RSA/IMT board would allow you to monitor Hardware events.

Configuring RSA II: [Configure RSA Board *PDF](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/systems/support/system_x_pdf/48p9832.pdf)

IBM Director can as well be configured to forward events even without the usage of IBM Director Manager, but this requires Tivoli Monitoring to capture Director events.

Answer (score 0):

If RSA II adapter is not available, then onboard BMC chip will also do the job nicely.  You can use OpenIPMI or practically any other IPMI-compliant tool to monitor it.